# Visual Studio: Collapse selected Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor

Everytime Visual Studio crashes all my arrays and functions unfold. I use Ctrl + M + O to collapse all the functions, but the arrays all remain unfolded.

I have very long double arrays (I know, I should be using classes, I'm a noob) where I'm forced to click on the [-] button at every entry to collapse the code unless I want to scroll through 2000 lines of code everytime. Is there any way to select and collapse all selected code?

[image]

Comment: *Warning: bad code indicator...*. You could use a `#region` directive around those. But yeah, you should be using a class instead

Comment: A workaround would be to put [`#region`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region) around them. And yes, it is sometimes considered a bad thing: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53086/207497

Comment: IMO you should move these arrays to a separate class, if you can. Or, they should be fetched from DB - which is better because inserting a new record to DB is easier than modifying C# code and recompiling it.

Comment: For me _control + m, m_ works also with arrays.

Comment: You should refactor each gun into its own class, with properties for WeaponID, Barrel Length, etc... You can then create a class that instantiates each weapon and returns an array of all weapons.

Comment: @JMad yes, that's what I should have done, but I'm not gonna do it all over again. I heard arrays are faster anyways. #region works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Arrays, select the code and Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>